# Unobserved variables in dowhy GCM

Tags: python, graph, dowhy, causal-inference

Stuck at a problem with dowhy, read the docs end to end, could not find an answer.
So imagine a simple graph:

```
X -> Y -> Z
```

X is present in the input data, so is Z. Y is not (unobserved). Can we get dowhy.gcm to treat such nodes as unobserved (like in dowhy.CausalModel)? When I try to auto-assign causal mechanism, the complains about Y missing from the data frame, no surprise.
What is the mechanism of including unobserved variables into the causal graph with GCMs? Thanks in advance!